# Cannot update my comment for a commit svn tortoise

Tags: tortoisesvn, comments

I want to update my own comment for a commit in the check-in history but I receive error as snapshot as below.

I understand that my account is not an admin/owner of the repository but it should be allowed me to update my own comment! On TFS side, I can do this actually.

Is there any work-around for me? I don't want to provide admin right to all users.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to give every user admin rights. But the error returned by your pre-revprop-change hook script tells you that only admins or **project owners** can change log messages.

So either change your pre-revprop-change hook script to allow all users to do that, or add yourself to the owners group or admin group.

Comment: It would be lovely if you would show me how to change the pre-revprop-change hook script. I'm using beanstalkapp.com's SVN service.

Comment: I see. This is not implemented by `benastalkapp` team